# Datagridview is completely hidden for bindingsource the second time

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, bindingsource

```
private void populateListingGrid(){

try{

Dictionary<string, Object> responseMap = new Dictionary<string, object>();                
PaginationList newContractDetailsListingMsDTO = getNewContractDetailsListingMsDTO();                
ContractService createContractService = ContractServiceFactory.getInstance();
responseMap = createContractService.getContractListing();                
contractList = responseMap["contractListingMsDTOs"] as List<NewContractListingMsDTO>;
this.newContractListingMsDTOBindingSource.Clear();
             if (contractList != null && contractList.Count > 0)
             {
                 newContractListingMsDTOBindingSource.DataSource = contractList;
                 newContractListDataGridView.Refresh();
             }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
   logger.Info("populateListingGrid");
}
}
```

I am using the `newContractListingMsDTOBindingSource` as a bindingsource, which works perfectly fine when i open the datagrid for first time, when i try to reopen the datagridview in winforms, entire datagridview seems crashed nothing is visible not even the column header of the bindingsource.

Am i using all the binding source or binding data source code correctly?

Comment: I'm asssuming your newContractListingMsDTOBindingSource is linked to the Datagridview. What line does the error occur at debug time?

Comment: There are no errors at all, niether at run time nor at compile time the table just disappears

Comment: So if I understand correctly, the DGV does not crash, the contents are not there (including table headers)?

Comment: If that's true then you need to look into your datasource (contractList) object.

Comment: the same data is coming everytime in the contractList object.

Comment: @dotNET can you help here?

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of trial and error, I found the solution to the problem, it worked when I set this property of the DataGridView:

```
ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode => AutoSize
```

If I change this property to `DisableResizing` / `EnableResizing`, the data grid view gets hidden the 2nd time. The problem is not with the `BindingSource` or `Datasource` directly.